# facebook login with php sdk on mobile

Tags: php, facebook, mobile

I have a weird problem with FB login on mobile devices. If I access the app with a normal computer it works fine. I am using the strandard php sdk provided by facebook.

When logging in through a mobile phone though, after putting in the credentials in the facebook page (of course the mobile version of facebook is served), the browser does not redirect to my app and stay on facebook. The url it gets stuck on is soemthing like this:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=MY_URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO&state=37620c215376cd419b67c1b97c7be827&scope=email%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++publish_actions&client_id=203992649788044&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&seen_v4_nux=0
```

**As I said on normal browsers it all works like a charm.**

I even added the "Mobile Web" option (in the app configuration on facebook developers panel) as I thought facebook might threat differently authentication requets when they are made to the mobile version but it still does not work. It gets stuck on the url I posted above and the page is totally blank!

Any idea?

Comment: `MY_URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO` is certainly not where you're going. What is exact URL you're using?

Comment: an existing one! I promise you. In fact when using a desktop browser it all works

Comment: Did you solve this issue? The same thing is happening to me. It goes blank, but I think that the https://m.facebook.com access point it's just extremely slow...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no control over Facebook, my best recommendation would be a redirect. You could try bit.ly or some service, or try a simple URL on your own site. Don't forget to escape any URL symbols.

For example, if your URL was:

```
http://www.mysite.co.ru/?o=XswINNsu&b=ugj8EVCz&B=D8CQ8FAK&H=2ekxsuuX&f=jbo8mZML&Z=uLius5xw&Y=64CvSA6e&z=fcRoF8Qd&s=omfQpdim&o=cKQ2.66&n=2SW3g9zs&V=iD8xV3Fk&R=6.cbWU1o&m=9T4Hpq5m&
```

Then you could convert it to:

```
http://www.mysite.co.ru/a/fromfb
```

...or even make another site:

```
http://www.myothersite-co-ru.com/a/fromfb
```

...and redirect to that big mess above:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A//www.myothersite-co-ru.com/a/fromfb
&state=37620c215376cd419b67c1b97c7be827
&scope=email%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++publish_actions
&client_id=203992649788044&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&seen_v4_nux=0
```